# How to print sent emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, printing

How do you print sent emails? I've tried right click print.  I don't see the Gmail icons that are in the inbox for printing.  Trying to print sent items with out the menu.

Answer (score 1):

- either click on the printer icon:

  [image: 0]

---

- to print individual emails:

  [image: 0]

---

- or press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`P`</kbd>** to invoke the printing overview

Comment: In sent items, there is no print icon. ctrl+p prints the menu as well.

Comment: for an icon to show up you need to enter the email

Comment: Went into email.  Still no icon.  Seems to be just on one email though now that I've tried others.  not sure why that is.

Comment: @user219566 answer updated